# Autoencoder using Backpropagation

Tags: python, algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement autoencoder using [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/) resource which implements backpropagation algorithm. I'm using the same feed forward algorithm implemented there but however it gives me a large error. In Autoencoders, the sigmoid function to be applied to the hidden for encoding and again to the output for decoding.

```
def feedForwardPropagation(network, row, output=False):
currentInput = row
if not output:
    layer = network[0]
else:
    layer = network[1]
layer_output = []
for neuron in layer:
    activation = neuron_activation(neuron['weights'], currentInput)
    neuron['output'] = neuron_transfer(activation)
    layer_output.append(neuron['output'])
currentInput = layer_output
return currentInput

def backPropagationNetworkErrorUpdate(network, expected):
for i in reversed(range(len(network))):
    layer = network[i]
    errors = list()
    if i != len(network) - 1:
        # Hidden Layers weight error compute
        for j in range(len(layer)):
            error = 0.0
            for neuron in network[i + 1]:  # It starts with computing weight error of output neuron.
                error += (neuron['weights'][j] * neuron['delta'])
            errors.append(error)
    else:
        # Output layer error computer
        for j in range(len(layer)):
            neuron = layer[j]
            error = expected[j] - neuron['output']
            errors.append(error)
    for j in range(len(layer)):
        neuron = layer[j]
        transfer = neuron['output'] * (1.0 - neuron['output'])
        neuron['delta'] = errors[j] * transfer

def updateWeights(network, row, l_rate, momentum=0.5):
for i in range(len(network)):
    inputs = row[:-1]
    if i != 0:
        inputs = [neuron['output'] for neuron in network[i - 1]]
    for neuron in network[i]:
        for j in range(len(inputs)):
            neuron['velocity'][j] = momentum * neuron['velocity'][j] + l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j]
            neuron['weights'][j] += neuron['velocity'][j]
        neuron['velocity'][-1] = momentum * neuron['velocity'][-1] + l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j]
        neuron['weights'][-1] += neuron['velocity'][-1]


def trainNetwork(network, train, l_rate, n_epoch, n_outputs, test_set):
hitrate = list()
errorRate = list()
epoch_step = list()
for epoch in range(n_epoch):
    sum_error = 0
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    for row in train:
        outputs = feedForwardPropagation(network, row)
        outputs = feedForwardPropagation(network, outputs)
        expected = row
        sum_error += sum([(expected[i] - outputs[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(expected))])
        backPropagationNetworkErrorUpdate(network, expected)
        updateWeights(network, row, l_rate)
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        errorRate.append(sum_error)
        epoch_step.append(epoch)
        log = '>epoch=%d, lrate=%.3f, error=%.3f' % (epoch, l_rate, sum_error)
        print(log, n_epoch, len(network[1][0]['weights']) - 1, l_rate)
return epoch_step, errorRate
```

For autoencoding I use one hidden layer, n inputs and n outputs. I believe I have gone wrong with the feedforward implementation. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I tried computing the weights after first layer (continue commented in feedforward method) and then decoding the output using the sigmoid function commented in trainNetwork method. However, the error didn't change after 100 epochs

Answer (score 1):

The characteristics of your problem (like error barely changing over 100 epochs, and remaining with a big error), suggest that the problem might be (and probably is) caused by the order of size of your input data, and the fact that you use sigmoids as activation function. I will give you a simple example:

Suppose I want to reconstruct the value  `x=100`. 
If I train it with an autoencoder on a single neuron, the reconstructed output will be given by `r = sigmoid(w*x)`, where the error is the difference between the actual input and the reconstruction, i.e. `e = x - r`. Note, that since a sigmoid function is bounded between -1 and 1 , the minimum error you can get in this case is `e = 100-1 = 99`. No matter how good you train the weight `w` in this case, `r=sigmoid(w*x)` would always be bounded by one.

This means that the sigmoid activation function is not able to represent your data in this case.
To solve this problem, either:

1. Downscale or Normalize your input data to a size between -1 and 1, or
2. Change the sigmoid to another activation function, that can actually reconstruct the right size of order of your data.

Hope this helps.